# Wordpress Cache Error

Tags: wordpress, memcached

I had purchased the collective theme yesterday from themefuse and when i uploaded the theme i got the following error:

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot find save handler 'memcache' - session startup failed in /home/makingfa/public_html/wp-content/themes/collective-parent/framework/core/SESSION.php on line 24

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot find save handler 'memcache' - session startup failed in /home/makingfa/public_html/wp-content/themes/collective-parent/framework/core/SESSION.php on line 24

I contacted the themefuse support and they responded as follows:
 "Please clear your browser cache and try one more time."

I cleared my browser cache both in Firefox and in IE but i still get the same error. Further i installed the WP Super Cahche plugin and deleted the cache via the plugin but again the error remains.

I am relatively new the WordPress and not sure if i am missing something here. Any help or info would be greatly appreciated as Themefuse support are not responding.

Many thanks

My site is http://www.makingfans.co.uk

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have the memcache package installed, or at least not enabled. Is this a server that you control? Supercache, among other things can persist some things to a memcache server, but if you haven't got it installed, then you can't use it.

The same applies to saving sessions into memcache - unless it's setup and running, you can't use it. If you do have access to edit php.ini, or if its within Wordpress, then for now, you have to turn it off and just go back to

```
session.save_handler = files  # in php.ini, or maybe set in a .htaccess
```

Comment: Hi Alister, thanks for the response. I am new at this and not that technical. My hosting is with Vidahost so i am guessing they control the server (I maybe wromg)? Would you recommend installing a memcache plugin - would that help as i am not technical?

Comment: You probably can't install the memcache plugin, and so you can't use it. Just use the normal files-based caching and session storage.

Comment: Really sorry Alister but im not sure exactly what i need to do...would you mind explaing in a dummies version?